# Allow some users free access to Windows 8 paid apps

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, winjs

I am deploying a Windows 8 application to the Store (paid app), however, I'd like to allow certain users to be able download it for free - not a trial version, but the full version. Is there a way to do this? Like if certain users have a special code?

I know we can install it locally if they have a developer's license, but that's not feasible for these users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if there is an "official" way of doing it,but for the group of folks who are helping me beta test my app I was going to give them a 24hr period to download the app and then set its price to free in the Store, then back to paid when done.

Of course my average download for that app is 5 or less day so I don't expect to lose a lot of revenue, if you are expecting 100's a day download it's probably not practical :D

Comment: That's actually pretty feasible - I've never switched between pricing models before though, what's the time frame between making the change and seeing it reflected in the Store?

Comment: Reasonably short I think, though I couldn't give you an exact time. I've changed the price on a couple of app before (though paid-paid not paid to free) and they seemed to change in 3-4 hours, that was a year ago, things might have changed now.